# Jquery Conflict between Autson Slideshow and Moset Tree

Tags: jquery

I have conflict between Autson Slideshow and Mosets Tree. I think it's due to the jquery conflict because when I try to open sub image in listing image normally they open in a lightbox but it's not the case. The image open in new window without any effects but if I disable the module Autson Slideshow it works fine. If I disable jquery from the module the module will not work and the image in Moset Tree work fine. What can I do?

I am using Joomla 1.6.5, Moset tree 2.2.4, and both use jquery-1.4.4.min, jquery.fancybox-1.3.4 and I am working on localhost .

Ask if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you J.Steel. I have many mistakes in my question. I am not good in english

Comment: Hi J.SteenCould you please tell me how to attach php file or how to email any other user

Comment: I am trying to contact users that they answer me but i could not

Answer (score 1):

Try including  `jQuery.noConflict();` in your script tag
Read more from http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply, i need to know where exactly insert this function i have 2 days searching about this problem and many person are talking about this solution but i don t know how to insert it nor where to find it

Comment: BUZZ i have this code in my mtree.php file $document->addCustomTag(' <script src="'.$mtconf->getjconf('live_site').'/components/com_mtree/js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');

  # Predefine variables:
  $prevar = " <script type=\"text/javascript\"><!-- \n";
  $prevar .= "jQuery.noConflict();\n";
  $prevar .= "var mtoken=\"".JUtility::getToken()."\";\n";
  $prevar .= "var mosConfig_live_site=\"".$mtconf->getjconf('live_site')."\";\n";

Comment: In the page where you are using these plugin include this code in start   of $(document).ready(function(){  ---here put this code---  })